# Capturing stream from usb camera without opening the browser using nodejs or python

Tags: python, node.js, video-streaming

i have made a P2P video streaming application using nodejs.Now i want to deploy that system on orange-pi and on orange-pi there are no browsers that support live streaming.So i was thinking that instead of opening the browser can i write a script in nodejs or python to capture stream directly from my orange-pi and send it to other peer?.Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: python `OpenCV` can read video (frame by frame) from file, local camera and streams - .

Comment: @furas thanks for replying but i am using RTC multiconnection library which is based on node js so i dont think that i will be able to make this system work correctly this is my last option

Comment: short way is `cvlc`,opencv, videocapture, etc, but point is did you want manage video streaming ?

Comment: @dsgdfg yes i do i dont think that i will be able to run my nodejs libraries with python can i? i have to send stream from one end to another

Comment: No way `send from other to other`, others why  trust you run 3rd prty software on pc ? Use browser but you need stream gateway  for protection clients.  Client to client connection(on stream) got a lot security bugs. Different os and devices, where midle point ? You can't manage stream if don't use your `stream gateway`.

Comment: @dsgdfg i dont think that os matter and as far as 3rd party software is concerned i dont need to install the application the other client will open it on its browser plus i have a server running between them that is operating on sockets.io which connects one client with other

Comment: You want use browser, browser don't support `python`, need use `jquery`, `ajax`, etc. No way, because client haven't any service for sharing camera, only able to Like this : Client <---> Server <------>Client